# Geoserver OAuth2 Community Extension - Java Runtime Error, possibly CORS?

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, cors, community, oauth2

I am trying to enable to OAuth2 community extension in Geoserver 2.24.2
I am running it on a Google Cloud Compute Engine VM as a .war on Tomcat9 proxying through NGINX (where I deal with SSL).

I get the OAuth2 login icon: [image]

And I am asked to login with a Google account, but after logging in I get this error in the browser:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Never should reach this point

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.RuntimeException: Never should reach this point
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerPreAuthenticatedUserNameFilter.getRoles(GeoServerPreAuthenticatedUserNameFilter.java:156)
    org.geoserver.security.oauth2.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationFilter.getRoles(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationFilter.java:175)
    org.geoserver.security.oauth2.GeoServerOAuthAuthenticationFilter.doAuthenticate(GeoServerOAuthAuthenticationFilter.java:346)
    org.geoserver.security.oauth2.GeoServerOAuthAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerOAuthAuthenticationFilter.java:153)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilterInternal(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:72)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:100)
    org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
    org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
    org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:357)
    org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:176)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.58 (Ubuntu)
```

I have enabled CORS in my `/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml` by uncommenting the two default code blocks:
[image]

Any ideas what I could do to get this working?

Comment: I should note, I have tried this version of the plugin: https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/2.24.x/community-latest/ and this version https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/main/community-latest/ and its the Google one we are using

Comment: What makes you think it is a CORS issue?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply Ian, I have been getting lots of CORS errors with my setup. Turns out I had headers being set in both NGINX and Tomcat and when I resolved that we managed to get the OAuth plugin to work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code shows:

```
    Collection<GeoServerRole> roles;
    if (PreAuthenticatedUserNameRoleSource.RoleService.equals(getRoleSource())) {
        roles = getRolesFromRoleService(request, principal);
    } else if (PreAuthenticatedUserNameRoleSource.UserGroupService.equals(getRoleSource())) {
        roles = getRolesFromUserGroupService(request, principal);
    } else if (PreAuthenticatedUserNameRoleSource.Header.equals(getRoleSource())) {
        roles = getRolesFromHttpAttribute(request, principal);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Never should reach this point");
    }
```

So I suspect that you haven't set up your `RoleSource` correctly. Though the exception message could help with a better message.